# Electric Current Power Calculations

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

With regards to the equations: $P=VI$ ; $P=V^2/R$ and $P=I^2R$, if you are given $P$, $V$, $I$ and $R$ for a circuit, how do you know which equation to use?

Does the use of an equation have to do with whether the circuit is in series or in parallel?

Answer (score 4):

They are all equivalent.  But if you are given P, V, R and I it doesn't make any sense to use any of the equatios you mentioned. What would you want to calculate?

Comment: You can see they are equivalent using Ohm's law: $V=IR$.

Answer (score 0):

$P= IV$ is fundamental, and applies to any circuit element (they have complex analogues too for time-varying circuits), whereas the equations containing $R$ are specific to resistors.

It doesn't matter if the circuit is in series or parallel. You just calculate equivalent resistance in each case.

Answer (score 0):

$$ V = I R \space \space \space \space \space   \space \space \space \space \space  or   \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space I = {V \over R}   \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space or  \space \space \space \space   \space \space \space \space \space  R={V \over I}$$
The basic equation for voltage across a resistor, current through a resistor and the resistance it has. All the same idea...

$$ P = V I  \space \space \space \space \space   \space \space \space \space \space  or   \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space I = {P \over V}   \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space or  \space \space \space \space   \space \space \space \space \space  V = {P \over I}$$
The power used by a section of a circuit is equal to the voltage across it multiplied by the current passing through.

All the equations you gave are based on the two formulas shown above. (Each shown 3 ways)

If you want to know about series or parallel than:

Parallel: Two parts of a circuit are in parallel if the current must split if it is going to pass through both parts. If this is the case than to find the total resistance we use:

$$ {1 \over R_{Total}} = {1 \over R_1}+{1 \over R_2}+{1 \over R_3} ... $$

$$ R_{Total} ={1 \over  {1 \over R_1}+{1 \over R_2}+{1 \over R_3} ...} $$

Series: Two parts of a circuit are in series if the current flowing through one part is by some amount the same current flowing through the other part. If all the current flowing through one part is the same current that will flow through the other part, than the total resistance is simple:
$$ R_{Total} = R_1+R_2$$

Hope that helps.